# Kafka Connect (BigQuery Sink) Create Field From Headers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using BigQuery Sink, is it possible to ingest headers as a field in BigQuery? Our producer sends common headers (keys as string values as byte arrays).

Is this something that can be done with connector configs? Or in any other way without modifying source code?

For example,

experimentation with with `header.converter`

```
"header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter" --> no effect
"header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.common.header" -> invalid value error when posting connector
"header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" --> no effect
"header.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleStringConverter" --> invalid value error when posting connector
```

experimentation with `transforms`, also resulting in invalid configuration

```
"transforms": "InsertField",
"transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Headers",
"transforms.InsertField.static.field": "$Headers.Key",
"transforms.InsertField.static.value": "$Headers.Value"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InsertField`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html) transform only supports keys and values.

Instead, you want [`HeaderToField`](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/HeaderToField.html) which comes from [`kafka-connect-transform-common` project](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common)

This answer applies to all connectors that do not natively support reading the Connect record headers.